Problematic HDMI/Displayport connection after second plugin
I have a Fedora 39 install and a MSI MAG 323UPFDE monitor.
Since the monitor has only one display port, I need to connect my laptop through an DisplayPort HDMI adapter. This is a DELOCK 66436 (https://www.delock.de/produkt/66436/merkmale.html?setLanguage=en).

Direct Diplay port connection: Works without any problems.
Display port -> DELOCK Adpapter -> HDMI: Works the first time with no problems. The second time no stable 4k 60 Hz connection can be established.

I could observe the behavior for the first and second HDMI port of the display. I am still trying to debug what causes the issue. Changing the freqency to something else than 60 hz does also not work.
I tried to remove the ~/.config/monitors.xml file but without any luck.
Therefore I wan to ask (since I could not find anything else): Are there other ways to reset in gnome the remembered monitors?
